# Xampp not working in UBUNTU 20.04 LTS

Tags: 20.04, apache2, php, lamp, xampp

**When I start my terminal by using :**
*sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start*

```
Starting XAMPP for Linux 7.4.9-0...
XAMPP: Starting Apache.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found
/opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found fail.

XAMPP:  Starting diagnose... 
XAMPP:  Sorry, I've no idea what's going wrong.
XAMPP:  Please contact our forum http://www.apachefriends.org/f/ 
Last 10 lines of "/opt/lampp/logs/error_log":
tail: cannot open '/opt/lampp/logs/error.log' for reading: No such file or directory
XAMPP: Starting MySQL.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found ok.
XAMPP: Starting ProFTPD.../opt/lampp/share/xampp/xampplib: line 22: netstat: command not found ok.
```

These were given my terminal and local is not showing php MYAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

I just faced this same issue & resolved it, when installed XAMP in Ubuntu 20.04lts. May be this is late reply, but this will help to someone.
It clearly says "netstat: command not found".

Run below command to install netstat:

```
sudo apt install net-tools
```

Then try to start your xampp again, it should work now.

```
sudo /opt/lampp/lampp start
```